# Does a program make a system call to get the value of an environment variable in linux?

Tags: linux, function, call, system

Or is it a function call? i know system calls are calls to a subroutine build in the system while function calls are calls within the program.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not programming-related and thus off-topic. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I believe it is implemented by glibc on Linux. I don't know if it entails a corresponding `syscall` from glibc. I suspect not since I believe its available in the process' environmental block. Also see [25.4.1 Environment Access](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Environment-Access.html) in the GNU C Library manual.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko I completely disagree with you. This is exactly the sort of questions SO was meant to answer: a novice trying to understand something about programming.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - there is no programming technology specified and it's not a programming problem in any way, it's something that can be read up in a book or tutorial of some sort. As much as I understand your point, I would be far from stating that this is exactly the sort of question SO was meant to answer.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko I think the question was quite clear despite "no programming technology specified". We're talking about a call to "getenv" in glibc. The question is obviously programming related. It makes no sense to ask this in the context of computer use.

Comment: I'll ask yourself these two questions: Is my answer a good answer to appear on SO, and does it directly answer the original question? If you answer yes to both, then the question is fine.

Comment: @ShacharShemesh - OK after some consideration I might sway towards your point of view of this not being completely off-topic, although I'd prefer to see some specific programming technology context in the question itself. What also puts me off here, is the encyclopedic character of the question, which makes it easily google-able. I don't believe there was any research done here prior to asking. But that's too much meta discussion for a comments section anyway. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 20):

No system call is done when reading environment variables.

On the C API level, the environment variables are passed to `main` as the third argument. The complete prototype is:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
```

If you define your main this way, you will not even need function call to read the environment.

The following program prints all of your environment variables:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {
    while( *envp ) {
        printf("%s\n", *envp);
        envp++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, `main` is just something invented by your compiler's runtime support libraries. As far as the OS is concerned, the interface is somewhat different. The same principle still stands, however. The environment is passed to the newly created program after `execve` on its stack.

This is also why `getenv` returns a `char *`. It does not need to allocate anything. It already has the string.

**Edited to add**: It is quite simple to know whether any specific function results in a system call or not (and which). All you have to do is run `strace` over the code. `strace` traps all (and only) system calls. If your `getenv` function call is invisible to it, it is not a system call.